# Logging for Azure graphapi

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

In my current environment in azure we are using azure graphapi mostly, for that we want to know who is doing what like logging of each request, when ever any request via graph api is there is option to see what data they access in azure portal?

Or logs for service principle also when ever any one logs in using service principle we wanted to know what actions they are doing.

Comment: Have you try any of the features from Azure Monitor?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/monitor-azure-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the log reports in the portal currently could not fully meet your requirements.

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Enterprise applications` -> find the service principal you want -> in `Sign-ins`, you could check the login information.

[image]

In this blade, you can just get the login information, the `Resource` is `Microsoft Graph`, but you could not know what actions they are doing via Microsoft Graph.

To check what actions the users are doing in the AAD tenant, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` -> `Audit logs`, you can check the users' actions, but you could not know if they did these things via Microsoft Graph/AAD Graph or not.

[image]

For more details, see [Sign-in logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins) and [Audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs).